# how to write it correctly in php? json

Tags: php, json

how to echo json in php? server sends me json.

```
$i=$_POST["id"];
if($i==1){

// here i must echo this

{

"item": 

{
        "html": 
[{

"description": "some text",
            "n": "1"
        }],
        "table": {

            "1": {

                "line": [{

                    "number": "",

                    "value": ""

                }

                ]
            }

        },
        "videos": [],

        "urlext": [],

        "imgs": [ {

            "size": {

                "root": "xxx xxx"

            }

        }]

    }

}


}
else {

// here i must echo another one

{

"item": 

{
        "html": 
[{

"description": "some text",
            "n": "1"
        }],
        "table": {

            "1": {

                "line": [{

                    "number": "",

                    "value": ""

                }

                ]
            }

        },
        "videos": [],

        "urlext": [],

        "imgs": [ {

            "size": {

                "root": "xxx xxx"

            }

        }]

    }

}


}


}
```

Comment: echo json_encode($yourContent);

Comment: [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). How did you not find this with Google, or even a search of this site????

Comment: SO is being bombarded with questions that show no effort of research, these days.. at least PHP questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just build an associative array of the data you need to send as json and use `json_encode()` to render json

```
$data = array( 'name' => 'foo',
               'some' => 'thing' 
);

echo json_encode($data);
```